# End of integer/structure array?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer, pass-by-pointer

```
Consider the following functions
void alloco(int **ppa)
{
    int i;
    printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa); /*this function allocates and fills 20 * sizeof(int) bytes */
    *ppa = (int *)malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    /*fill all 20 * sizeof(int) bytes */
}

int main()
{
    int *app = NULL;
    int i;
    printf("inside main\n");
    alloco(&app);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++) /*ISSUE::how will i know to traverse only 20 indexes?*/
    printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);
    return(0);
}
```

Basically how will main() come to know number of bytes to traverse i.e memory allocated by alloco() function. Is there any delimiter like NULL in character arrays?

Comment: if you really need to do this without passing the size then either you need to fill the delimiter yourself or need to rely on the platform specific implementation of malloc to access the header.

Comment: C-"strings" (`char` arrays) are terminated by `NUL` aka `null` aka `'\0'`, but surely not by `NULL`, the latter is something different.

Comment: If this pattern occurs frequently you may want to have a struct keeping track of the length of data pointed to by its second member, a pointer. Or you use a language which has that structure in its standard library ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible, you need to keep that value somewhere, for example you could do this,

```
void alloco(int **ppa, int count)
{
    int i;

    printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa);
    *ppa = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    if (*ppa == NULL)
        return;
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
        /* fill it here. */
}

int main()
{
    int *app;
    int  i;
    int  count;

    count = 20;
    app = NULL;
    printf("Inside main\n");
    alloco(&app, count);
    if (app == NULL)
        return -1;    
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);
    /* done with `app' */
    free(app);
    return 0;
}
```

Many other combinations could work, for example

```
int alloco(int **ppa)
{
    int i;

    printf("inside alloco %d\n",ppa);
    *ppa = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    if (*ppa == NULL)
        return;
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
        /* fill it here. */
    return 20;
}

int main()
{
    int *app;
    int  i;
    int  count;

    printf("Inside main\n");

    app = NULL;
    count = alloco(&app);
    if (app == NULL)
        return -1;    
    for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);
    /* done with `app' */
    free(app);
    return 0;
}
```

But I personally don't like this because if there is going to be a fixed number of integers it's not a good idea to use `malloc()` just,

```
int main()
{
    int  app[20];
    int  i;

    printf("Inside main\n");    
    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(app) / sizeof(app[0]) ; i++)
        printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, app[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you sure? if that is the case 'count' variable what you used there needs to be defined by alloco in my case so i need to pass by reference this count to alloco function, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think you are trying to do something with ideas from some other programming language, can you explain why do you want to do this? See the second solution that I proposed, it's very bad design to decide the size of the buffer in the allocator function, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No, nothing like that, my requirement is something like this - main() gives alloco() a NULL pointer, alloco needs to fill this(based on output of some other functions) and tell main() till where to read(if you're correct).

Comment: :D My use-case is like that, hence the question. @iharob

Comment: It seems you meant passing and setting &count, not count.

Comment: @Coder passing out-parameter or contracting on terminator or fixed size is idiomatic C.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any delimiter like NUL<strike>L</strike> in character arrays?

If you define one, yes.

This however only is possible if your use case does not need all possible integer values.

If for example you would only need positive values including `0` you can define the value of `-1` to be the "End-of-Array" marker.

You then would allocate one more element to the array then you need and assign `-1` to this additional very last array element.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc */
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

#define EOA (-1)

int array_allocate(int ** ppi)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL = ppi)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t number_of_elements = ...; /* Assign some positive value here. */

    *ppi = malloc((number_of_elements + 1) * sizeof ** ppi);
    if (NULL == *ppi)
    {
      result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      (*ppi)[number_of_elements] = EOA;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

ssize_t array_number_of_elements(int * pi)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == pi)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    int * pi_tmp = pi;
    while (EOA != *pi_tmp)
    {
      ++pi_tmp;
    }

    result = pi_tmp - pi;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for size_t and ssize_t */
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf and perror */

int array_allocate(int **);
ssize_t array_number_of_elements(int *);

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
  int * pi = NULL;

  if (-1 == array_allocate(&pi))
  {
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    perror("array_allocate() failed");
  }
  else
  {
    ssize_t result_number_of_elements = array_number_of_elements(pi);
    if (-1 == result_number_of_elements)
    {
      result = EXIT_FAILURE;
      perror("array_number_of_elements() failed");
    }
    else
    {
      size_t number_of_elements = result_number_of_elements;
      printf("The number of array's elements is %zu.\n", 
        number_of_elements);
    }
  }

  free(pi); /* Clean up. */

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It takes becoming a 3-Star Programmer**

You can easily allocate some fixed number of elements (less than the maximum) in an function without passing the number of elements between the caller function and the callee. However, it takes creating an **array of pointers to pointers to type** How/Why? Essentially, you are treating your array as a null-terminated string, initially allocating all pointers to type within the array to `NULL` and only allocating space for them as needed. (allocating with `calloc` makes this a snap) When the array is used back in the caller, it allows iterating over all **filled** values until your reach the first null-pointer.

Now granted,

> simply passing a **pointer to size** as an additional argument to your
>   function makes much more sense [1]

and eliminates the need for a triple-star rating, but for the purpose of example, enjoy being a **3-Star Programmer** for a while:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITSZ 21

void alloco (int ***ppa)
{
    printf("inside %s\n", __func__);

    int i = 0;

    /* allocate 21 pointers-to-int */
    if (!(*ppa = calloc (INITSZ, sizeof **ppa))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* allocate/fill 20 values (or anything less than 21) */
    for (i = 0; i < INITSZ - 1; i++) {
        if (!((*ppa)[i] = calloc (1, sizeof ***ppa))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *((*ppa)[i]) = i * 2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **app = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    printf ("inside main\n");
    alloco (&app);

    /*ISSUE::how will i know to traverse only 20 indexes?*/

    while (app[i]) {
        printf("app[%d] = %d \n", i, *(app[i]));
        i++;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/alloc_array+1
inside main
inside alloco
app[0] = 0
app[1] = 2
app[2] = 4
app[3] = 6
app[4] = 8
app[5] = 10
app[6] = 12
app[7] = 14
app[8] = 16
app[9] = 18
app[10] = 20
app[11] = 22
app[12] = 24
app[13] = 26
app[14] = 28
app[15] = 30
app[16] = 32
app[17] = 34
app[18] = 36
app[19] = 38
```

**footnote [1]:** emphasis added to the quote for clarity that this solution was intended to show what was possible, not what was most efficient or most practical.

Comment: You are aware that this approach (on a 64bit system at least) takes 3 times the memory as a when using a linear array.

Comment: Two bugs here: 1st: This: `(**ppa)[i] = i * 2;` shall be `*((*ppa)[i]) = i * 2`;` and 2nd this `printf("app[%d] = ... (*app)[i]);` shall be `printf("app[%d] = ... *(app[i]));`

Comment: I appreciate the bug fixes. As to the memory, this was not intended as an efficiency candidate, it was meant as an **impractical solution to the exact questions asked**. That is why it was clearly qualified with **passing a pointer to size as an additional argument to your function makes much more sense**. Thanks.